# Defining routes in constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have a component called `Root` which renders the Routes for my `index.js`

```
const store = configureStore();
ReactDOM.render(
  <Root store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

I need to do this because I am connecting `Root` to `redux`, this is due to root authorization with `onEnter`, and it needs to work with `redux` state.

So here is the Root:

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // some stuff
  }

  requireAuthentication = (nextState, replace) => {
    // some stuff for managing auth
  };

  render() {
    const { store } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
              <Route component={Dashboard}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home} onEnter={requireAuthentication}/>
              </Route>
              <Route path="login" component={Login} />
            </Route>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// some definitions for connecting Root to redux

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Root);
```

Ok... this renders well, but I have a warning:

```
Warning: [react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored
```

routes, also works fine... but I want to solve the warning. So... googling I found the problem an a possible solution: declare `routes` inside the constructor and pass it to `Router` via `props`.

My constructor I did this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { loginActions } from '../actions';
import { App, Dashboard, Home, Login } from '../features';
import adalHandler from '../services/adal';

class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const routes = (
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route component={Dashboard}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      </Route>
    );
    // some stuff
    }
  }

  requireAuthentication = (nextState, replace) => {
    // stuff
  };

  render() {
    const { store } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={browserHistory} routes={this.routes} />
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// stuff

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Root);
```

but now, it is no rendering well.

How can I solve it?

Comment: This may not be the issue but I do notice there is no route for `Dashboard` here: `<Route component={Dashboard}>` and because of this the nested `IndexRoute` had no index route to follow. Try setting a test route for `Dashboard` and see if that error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object `this.routes` isn't defined in the render method.

For example you can replace `const routes = (...);` in constructor with `this.routes = (...);` to make object accessible in the render method.